# Showing a functor that preserves coequalizers is faithful

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

While studying for an algebra exam I came across this problem:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be categories, and suppose that every pair of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ admits a coequalizer. Let $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ be a functor that preserves coequalizers. Suppose also that if $h$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $F(h)$ is an isomorphism, then $h$ is an isomorphism. Show that $F$ is faithful.

I was thinking to prove this by contradiction, so I considered two morphisms $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : A \rightarrow B$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $F(f) = F(g)$ but $f \neq g$. I took $\pi : B \rightarrow Q$ to be the coequalizer of $f, g$ in $\mathcal{C}$; then since $F$ preserves coequalizers, we know that the coequalizer of $F(f), F(g)$ in $\mathcal{D}$ is $F(\pi) : F(B) \rightarrow F(Q)$. My hope was that I could then use the universal property to get a contradiction, but I didn't know what to contradict, and I also didn't see how to use the fact that $F(h)$ is an isomorphism implies $h$ is an isomorphism.

How should one proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use contradiction. You start well: say $f,g\colon A\to B$ in $\mathscr{C}$ have $F(f)=F(g)$. Let $\pi\colon B\to Q$ be the coequalizer of $f$ and $g$.

1. Prove that the coequalizer of a map with itself (in any category) is the identity morphism on the image.
2. Conclude that $F(\pi)$ is an isomorphism.
3. Deduce that $\pi$ is an isomorphism.
4. Conclude that $\mathrm{id}_B$ is also a coequalizer of $f$ and $g$.
5. Use that to conclude that $f=g$.